# Problemas al usar attr (JQuery)

Tags: html, jquery

Anduve haciendo un *toggle* de mostrar y ocultar la contraseña de los *inputs*; tengo 2  *inputs* en el cual al darle al icono `div class="icon icon-view"`, en los dos se muestre y oculte.

Pero solo funciona una sola vez y no vuelve los *inputs a `type="password"`*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#view").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("icon-view-active");
      if ($(":password").attr("type","password")){
        $(':password').attr("type", "text");
       }
       else{
        $(':password').attr("type", "password");
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-float">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..." required>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="password-verify">
    <input type="password" name="password_verify" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..."required>
    <div class="icon icon-view" id="view">clic aqui</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los problemas radican en el selector que estás utilizando en jQuery. `$(":password"` va a devolverte todos los *inputs* cuyo tipo sea `"password"`, por eso funciona la primera vez. Luego, ya no tendrán ese tipo y el selector devuelve un conjunto de resultados vacío.

Una forma de solucionarlo es ponerles a todos una clase particular, que te permita luego seleccionarlos, por ejemplo, la clase `"pwd"`, y utilizar el selector de clase `".pwd"` en jQuery.

El otro problema que tienes es que en el `if` no estás comparando el atributo, sino asignándolos.

Al juntar ambas cosas, tenemos el código de esta forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#view").click(function() {
    if ($(".pwd").attr("type")=="password") {
      $(".pwd").attr("type", "text");
    } else {
      $(".pwd").attr("type", "password");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-float">
  <input class="pwd" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..." required>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="password-verify">
    <input class="pwd" type="password" name="password_verify" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..."required>
    <div class="icon icon-view" id="view">clic aqui</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

cuando pones:

```
if($(":password").attr("type","password")) // aqui no estas preguntando si el type de tu input es password, en lugar de esto se lo estas asignando.
```

es por esa razon que solo ocurre una vez, porque el retorna true, que significa que si asigno type = password al input deseado y despues le dirige el type a ser text, y queda en un bucle infinito, ya que la condicional es en palabras: "se agrego password como type a :password? a lo que siempre retornara como true.

mejor pon :

```
if($(":password").attr("type") == "password") // asi se comprobara que type corresponde a password
```

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la que solo funciona una vez es porque buscas inputs del tipo password `$(":password").attr("type","password")` y en la segunda vez pues ya no son tipo password sino text, sin mencionar que no haces una comparación del atributo type, lo más fácil es ponerles una clase y operar sobre ella así:

```
$("#view").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("icon-view-active");
    if ($(".clase").attr("type") == "password"){
        $('.clase').attr("type", "text");
    }
    else{
        $('.clase').attr("type", "password");
    }
    });

<div class="form-float">
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..." required class="clase">
 <div class="password-verify">
      <input type="password" name="password_verify" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..."required class="clase">
      <div class="icon icon-view" id="view">VER</div>
 </div>
```

Lo del usuario hay varias formas, básicamente todas concuerdan en hacer un corte del mail en el "@"(sin incluirlo) y concatenarlo al número aleatorio.

Para el número existe `Math.random()`, solo regresa un número entre 0 y 1(nunca regresara a) así que deberás de hacer el ajuste correspondiente, por ejemplo:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);//Número entre 1 y 100
```

Otra manera es hacer un conteo de usuarios con ese username, sin el número, registrados en la base de datos y concatenar ese número.

Espero sea de ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#view").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("icon-view-active");
    $('input').attr("type", $('input').attr('type') === 'text' ? 'password' : 'text' )
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-float">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..." required>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="password-verify">
    <input type="password" name="password_verify" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..."required>
    <div class="icon icon-view" id="view">clic aqui</div>
  </div>
</div>
```